# Вывести переменную в textarea

Tags: javascript

Как переменную вывести в поле textarea с ID **copy-code**?

**Пример, того, что предполагается вставить в форму:**

```
<button class="button button_theme_normal button_size_s z-calculator__btn z-calculator__btn_size_m i-bem button_js_inited" data-bem="{&quot;button&quot;:{},&quot;z-calculator__btn&quot;:{&quot;action&quot;:&quot;ins&quot;,&quot;arg&quot;:&quot;9&quot;}}" role="button" type="button"><span class="button__text">Кнопка</span></button>
```

prompt выводит нужный результат, а вот другие способы не работаю (разные пробовал).

```js
 'use strict';

 var passateCode, copyCode;

 document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
   passateCode = document.getElementById('passate-code').value;
   copyCode = passateCode.replace(/( class=".*?")( data-bem=".*?")?( role=".*?" )?(type=".*?")?/gm, '');

   prompt('Скопировать', copyCode); //как видите, prompt выводит нужный результат
 });
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>Чистка HTML кода от мусора</h2>
    <p>Это очень просто, скопируйте ваш "загрязненный" код, и вставте в форму ниже, после нажатия на копку "почистить" всплывет окно с результатом.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <form class="passate-code">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="passate-code"></label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="passate-code" placeholder="Вставить код"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="copy-code">Скопируйте код</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="copy-code"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="почистить">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вот готовый пример http://artlenk.ru/blog/js/services-html-clearing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Осталось просто присвоить нужный текст свойству *value* у *textarea*

```
document.getElementById('copy-code').value = copyCode;
```

Кроме того у вас не совсем верное регулярное выражение, например для

```
<button class="button button_theme_normal button_size_s z-calculator__btn z-calculator__btn_size_m i-bem button_js_inited" data-bem="{&quot;button&quot;:{},&quot;z-calculator__btn&quot;:{&quot;action&quot;:&quot;ins&quot;,&quot;arg&quot;:&quot;9&quot;}}" type="button" role="button"><span class="button__text">Кнопка</span></button>
```

Ответ будет отличаться от того которые вы ожидаете от разметки в посте, так как в html не важен порядок атрибутов, а в вашем регулярном выражении - важен.

Регулярное выражение можно заменить, например, на такое

```
/(\s*class=".*?"\s*)|(\s*data-bem=".*?"\s*)|(\s*role=".*?"\s*)|(\s*type=".*?"\s*)/gm
```

```js
'use strict';

var passateCode, copyCode;

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
  passateCode = document.getElementById('passate-code').value;
  copyCode = passateCode.replace(/(\s*class=".*?"\s*)|(\s*data-bem=".*?"\s*)|(\s*role=".*?"\s*)|(\s*type=".*?"\s*)/gm, '');

  prompt('Скопировать', copyCode);
  document.getElementById('copy-code').value = copyCode;
});
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>Чистка HTML кода от мусора</h2>
    <p>Это очень просто, скопируйте ваш "загрязненный" код, и вставте в форму ниже, после нажатия на копку "почистить" всплывет окно с результатом.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
      <form class="passate-code">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="passate-code"></label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="passate-code" placeholder="Вставить код"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="copy-code">Скопируйте код</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="copy-code"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="почистить">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за регулярное выражение! Я тоже использовал **document.getElementById('copy-code').value = copyCode;**

но не работало, оно вставляется и быстро исчезает, оказывается, это виновата кнопка input, когда на нее нажимаю, браузер перезагружает страницу и все переменные чистятся!!!

я ее просто поменял на другой элемент div

Comment: @alex-lenk, достаточно было заменить `type="submit"` на `type="button"`